# Fortran runtime error: Bad value during floating point read

Tags: fortran

I am trying to read a Tab-delimited text file, using "gfortran" in Ubuntu-13. I get following error
"Fortran runtime error: Bad value during floating point read"

Program is given below;

```
    CHARACTER*8 STID
       OPEN (8,FILE='station.txt', STATUS='OLD',FORM='FORMATTED')
       OPEN (10,FILE='stn.dat',FORM='UNFORMATTED')
       IFLAG = 0
C  Read and Write
10     READ (8,9000,END=90) IYEAR,IMONTH,STID,RLAT,RLON,RVAL
9000   FORMAT (I4,T1,I2,T1,A8,3F5.1)
       IF (IFLAG.EQ.0) THEN
          IFLAG = 1
          IYROLD = IYEAR
          IMNOLD = IMONTH
       ENDIF
C  If new time group, write time group terminator.
C  Assuming no empty time groups.
       IF (IYROLD.NE.IYEAR.OR.IMNOLD.NE.IMONTH) THEN
          NLEV = 0
          WRITE (10) STID,RLAT,RLON,TIM,NLEV,NFLAG
          ENDIF
          IYROLD = IYEAR
          IMNOLD = IMONTH
C  Write this report
       TIM = 0.0
       NLEV = 1
       NFLAG = 1
       WRITE (10) STID,RLAT,RLON,TIM,NLEV,NFLAG
       WRITE (10) RVAL
       GO TO 10
C  On end of file write last time group terminator.
90     CONTINUE
       NLEV = 0
       WRITE (10) STID,RLAT,RLON,TIM,NLEV,NFLAG
       PRINT *, STID,RLAT,RLON,TIM,NLEV,NFLAG
       STOP
       END
```

The input text file looks like

```
1985    11      AAAA    18.2    42.7    9.2
1985    11      BBBB    25.3    49.5    0.0
1985    11      cccc    21.5    41.6    22.6
1985    11      ddddd   29.8    40.1    3.6
....    ..      .....   ....    ....    ...
```

Comment: Welcome, please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Be sure to take the welcome [Tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Your program is not complete. We are missing many variable declarations. Or are they really missing? Do you use `IMPLICIT NONE`? You really, really, really should. And learn modern Fortran, your style is from a different century, one should not program like that now.

Comment: One if your ifs is also missing an `END IF`. Please read [mcve] and supply a real code.

Comment: For a simple well-structured data file such as illustrated here it's almost always going to be easier to use *list directed* reading, perhaps `READ (8,*,END=90) IYEAR,IMONTH,STID,RLAT,RLON,RVAL`, than fiddle around with the precise format.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone! I have solved the problem by using your suggestions i.e declaring variables, using modern fortran syntex and using list directed reading.